6 Sided Cross Burr Puzzle
I have been trying to solve this for several hours and haven’t figured out how to get the final piece to slide in. Though the final shape looks like many other puzzles, none of the solutions I’ve found in my research match mine. (I’ve looked here at puzzling stack exchange, 2 academic-looking articles on the puzzle type, the Wikipedia page for this variety of puzzle, and extensively through Google images.)


How can this be solved?

This seems to be the Artifactory 5-4 puzzle, which has a very complex set of movements required for (dis)assembly.
Found this image on imgur (using a google search) which seems to depict the solution:

 

Couldn't figure out who had made the animation though.

Thank you so much!! This is indeed it and I was able to solve it thanks to that graphic.
